# There was no documentation describing why should use CreateMap() when using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Why should I configure mappings using AutoMapper while it works fine without any CreateMap ?

Comment: This post will self destruct momentarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the proper medium for this type of question but I'll answer anyways. I would imagine they do have documentation somewhere.

The cost of creating a map is high. By using create map, the mapping will be created on app start rather than during use. You can pretty easily tell the difference by timing the model mapping with and without create map.

You will also use this to define any custom mapping.